# How did Denmark manage to create multiple strong and enduring political parties despite having a 2% electoral threshold?

Tags: parliament, proportional-representation, denmark

The current [Folketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folketing) (Danish Parliament) has a 2% electoral threshold for its levelling seats. This means that any party that has received 2% of the national vote share can get into the Parliament.

Under this system, you'd think that the country would experience intense party fragmentation, and while the Folketing does host a relatively large amount of political parties by European standard, these parties tend to be very stable and enduring after several electoral cycles.

The two biggest parties are almost always Social Democrat (center-left) and Venstre (center-right). While the junior partners tend to be the same parties as well. Political parties also consistently coalesce under two major coalitions (i.e. red block and blue block) before election.

How did this stable dynamic come about?

Comment: Do you have any concrete comparative data to suggest that Denmark is actually an outlier in this sense? Aren't the major parties pretty stable and enduring in most other European countries too? In terms of overall [effective number of parties](https://whogoverns.eu/party-systems/effective-number-of-parties/) Denmark is decisively average.

Comment: @BrianZ Denmark is an outlier because it has a 2% electoral threshold - the only kind in this world. Most other European countries have much higher thresholds, ranging from 3% to 5%. It's expected that other countries have more stable political ecosystem, but Denmark is unusually stable given the system it operates in.

Comment: @BrianZ Also the data you cited are not standardized based on date. For instance, the number from Denmark is between 1910-2020, but the number from Germany is between 1919-1933, the number from Estonia is between 1920 - 1934. And for some reason Czechoslovakia is mentioned twice(?) They should all be standardized to 2020.

Comment: Why would you assume otherwise? The same is true in Italy (pre-recent reforms) with five main stable parties, in the post-WWII era, and in Israel. Multi-party does not mean instability of parties, it can cause instability of coalitions if the country is underlyingly divided.